# Cannot access web server locally, clearos

Tags: web-server, clearos

I just did a fresh install of ClearOS 7.2 (I had an install of 7.12 running for months but reinstalled for a few reasons), and have everything configured but I cannot access my web server locally. I have a few domains, all can be accessed off my LAN. If I SSH into the server I can successfully ping the domains and the proper IP is returned. If I ping the domains from a machine that is not the server (that is on the LAN) then it never connects, times out.

The web servers are enabled and I have added a rule in the firewall for port 80. They work out in the world I just need to be able to see them locally too.

I have no idea what went wrong. Can I add a rule for iptables to resolve this? I can add a custom rule. ClearOS forums are useless, never any help there. Any ideas? I  know enough about linux to be dangerous. The machine is a home-office server, so I can do anything that needs to be done.

Comment: Can you clarify please? What do you mean by locally? And domains? Is the web server installed on your ClearOS server or is it some other system? What web server software are you using? Can you show some debugging steps, IP addresses, config file info, etc...? Anything more to help us help you.

Comment: Locally as in a machine on the same LAN. I have tried linux, osx and windows machines, all the same result - no connection, times out. Domains as in website domains, hatethis.org is one of them. The ClearOS box handles the webserver. The software is ClearOS, its a distro for small offices, utm, file sharing etc. It uses iptables for the firewall and apache/php/mariadb as the LAMP stack.

Comment: I am thinking something went wrong with the install. It should work out of the box, as before. ClearOS has a GUI to interact with the entire system, firewall rules, websites, all added from there. Debugin steps I tried, the firewall has a port 80 rule, the server is added and enabled (hatethis.org) and that should be that. But for some reason ClearOS is not passing the traffic through to the machines on the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. It was fixed by creating DNS entries for the domains and pointing them to the gateway/web server (ClearOS). I don't remember having to do this step in previous installations.